# Why are some of my api calls unnecessarily getting redirected to same URI?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey-2.0

I am seeing this strange behaviour:
[image]

Running on Google App Engine (Java) and using Jersey 2.5.1 for my APIs. This is only happening for some URIs (and for them it's happening consistently).

Comment: Is this HTTP -> HTTPS?

Comment: Hmm... could be... can't be sure...